# Sum of all the elements in an array with ExecutorService pool not working

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I am trying to understand ExecutorService and i want to do the sum of all the elements of an array. I did two methods, one that makes the sum serially (just a for loop that sums all the elements) and other concurrently with a pool. My problem is that the total sum from using ExecutorService is off with the serial sum almost all the time, sometimes even just by one.

```java
package sumArregloConc;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SumaArregloMain {

    private final static int cantElem = 1000;
    private static ExecutorService tpool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] arreglo = generarArreglo(cantElem); //generate the array with random numbers

        System.out.println(sumaSerial(arreglo));
        System.out.println(sumaConcurrente(arreglo));
    }

    public static int sumaSerial(int[] arreglo)
    {
        int suma = 0;
        for(int i =0; i< arreglo.length; i++)
        {
            suma += arreglo[i];
        }

        return suma;

    }

    public static int sumaConcurrente(int[] arreglo)
    {
        AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger(0);

        for(int i = 1 ; i < cantElem; i++){

            int a = arreglo[i];
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        int res = a;
                        total.addAndGet(res);
                        return;
                }});
                tpool.submit(thread);
        }

        tpool.shutdown(); //wait for everything to finish
        return total.get();
    }

    public static int[] generarArreglo(int cantElem)
    {
        int[] arreglo = new int[cantElem];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < cantElem; i++)
        {
            arreglo[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
        }

        return arreglo;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell what is wrong?

Comment: You need to call `awaitTermination()` on your thread pool. Just calling shutdown will disallow new tasks to be submitted but it doesn't wait for queued/executing tasks to finish.

Comment: Also, it's a bit unusual to submit threads to an `ExecutorService` (is this even possible??). Just submit `Runnable`s instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i added it to my code. Anyway i found the real bug. It was that instead of starting at i = 0 it starts from i = 1

Comment: @Eric it’s not unusual, it’s an error. It’s a historical design mistake that `Thread` implements `Runnable`, which invites to make such errors (and has no actual use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. First what Eric said about awaitTermination and Runnable, but the main bug was just that the loop started at i = 1 instead of i = 0, silly mistake.

```java
    public static int sumaConcurrente(int[] arreglo)
    {
        AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger(0);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < cantElem; i++){

            int a = arreglo[i];

            tpool.submit(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    total.addAndGet(a);
                    return;
                    }
                });
        }

        tpool.shutdown(); //wait for everything to finish
        try {
              tpool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            }
        return total.get();
    }
```